# Custom note heads in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

I am attempting to replace the default note heads with custom graphics in Lilypond. I've read the documentation under A. 10.3 Graphic which explains how to use `\markup` to add graphics to a score, however I'm stuck at being able to use those to replace note heads. My question is how can I replace the default note heads for custom ones?

Comment: Could you please try to better explain what is your problem, to me your question seems really vague. What do you mean by "change notations"? What are you trying to accomplish with the markup graphics? Also, please post a working minimal example, the code you posted above won't compile since it depends on several variables (e.g. PartPOneVoiceOne) which are not present.

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f the question was answered by Paco as is.

Comment: which does not mean your question was clear. Your minimal example above is broken and your text is unclear.

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f So if it's so unclear how come he answered it with no questions?

Comment: oh please, give me a break. Since when does "notations" mean note heads? Since are non-compilable minimal examples acceptable here? Paco's answer even starts with "If I understand correctly [...]" since he is guessing what you meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to make some noteheads substituted by arbitrary graphics. Assuming you already have the graphic in EPS format as sol.eps, this code uses it to change a 'g' to a picture of a sun ('sol' is Spanish for 'sun'):

```
cabezaSol = {
 \once \override NoteHead  #'stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
 \once \override NoteHead #'text =
   \markup {
     \general-align #Y #CENTER {
       \epsfile #X #2 #"./sol.eps"
     }
   }
 }
{ e'4 f' \cabezaSol g' }
```

[image]

Comment: would you know how I can make this global? By this i mean currently for each note name I have to set the variable in front of it.  What i would like is to make it where ALL G's for example have the cabezaSol.  Whether they are g1 g4 etc. @Paco

Comment: This code based on LSR could help. http://lilybin.com/jh5wta/1 It applies a notehead style to g only but for sure it can be modified to override to an arbitrary graphic notehead.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Paco